# Crystal Report with multiple text fields, heading and details come on seprate pages?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I am generating a contract document with Crystal Reports which has multiple formatted paragraphs with headings. Data is not coming from database so I am using mostly text objects and parameter fields to display content.

The issue is on some pages paragraph heading come on bottom of page and paragraph text comes on next page. Please advice me is there a way I can combine paragraph heading (which is a separate text object) with paragraph text (which is an other text object), so that they both come on same page.

Strange thing is this it passes paragraph on next page sometimes even if there is space on bottom of page.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
Report will be printed on a fixed size A4.

Comment: The space which u see in bottom may be different sections (like report footer, page footer). Can u tell me in which section u use the Paragraphs ?

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting from crystal reports to another format to see if the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Issue is same while exporting data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use Multiple sections (detail, header, footer) and adjust the size of the section to push the paragraph onto the next page.  I've done something similar in both Infomaker & Crystal to have the reports align correctly.